# Prove this action is properly discontinuous..

Tags: manifolds, group-actions

Consider the group $\mathbb Z_2=\{0, 1\}$ acting on the sphere $\mathbb S^n$ through the group actions $\psi_0=Id$ and $\psi_1=-Id$. Show this actions is properly discontinuos? The definition of properly discontinuity I'm using is: Let $G$ a group and $\psi_g$ an action on a topological space $X$, then $\psi_g$ is said to be properly discontinuous if for every $x\in X$ there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U\cap \psi_g(U)=\phi$ for all $g\in G$ with $g\neq e$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

(1) Clearly the group is discrete...

(2) The inverse image of any compact subset of $\,S^n\,$ is compact...which is also clear.

The above already makes it prop. disc., but with your definition perhaps the way is a little longer:

Since the only non-trivial element of the group maps points on the sphere to its antipodes (=opposite points), you can take even a huge open neighborhood of any $\,x\in S^n\,$ , say half the half sphere determined by the midpoint of the sphere's diameter joining $\,x\,,\,-x\,$, and then clearly $ 1\cdot U\cap U=\emptyset\,$ , as $\,1\cdot U\,$ will be all the opposite (antipode) points of $\,U\,$ ...

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try to write the proof =D

Comment: ¿cómo se puede hacer un prueba formal de esto? ¿cómo es $U$ explícitamente?

Comment: @user402543 Creo que lo anterior es completamente formal...aunque no completamente explícito.

Comment: Ok, pienso lo mismo, tal vez no utilicé bien las palabras. ¿cómo puedo tomar $U$?

Comment: @user402543 Toma el círculo grande (o sea, cuyo centro es el origen)  que une a $\;x,\,-x\in S^n\;$ , y sobre este círculo marca el punto medio $\,p\,$ del segmento de perímetro uniendo a $\;x,\,-x\;$  . Sea $\,U\,$ el hemisferio *abierto* determinado por los dos polos y por $\,p\,$ que contiene a $\,x\,$ ...y ya. Si $\,x\,$ es uno de los polos estonces toma el hemispherio determinado por el Ecuador...